# Modified version of the Secretary Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A firm is about to hire (exactly) one of the three candidates who take a test whose scores are continuous random variables $\sim \text{Unif}[0,100]$. The candidates apply sequentially, so either a candidate is selected and no further candidate is selected or a candidate is rejected for good. The hiring committee does not know the score of the next candidate when they are reviewing the scores of a particular candidate. If the first two are rejected, the last candidate has to be selected. Given this information, what's the score below which the first candidate and the second candidate will be rejected if the firm wants to maximize the expected score of the admitted candidate?

---

Suppose the scores (*marks*) are $M_i \sim U[0,100]$ for $i=1,2,3$. I figured out the expected score of the third candidate is $50$. So the second candidate is rejected when $P(M_2 < M_3) < P(M_2 \geq M_3) \iff \frac{100-M_2}{100} < \frac{M_2}{100} \iff M_2 < 50$. This means that the second candidate will be rejected if he scores below $50$.

How do I find the range of scores which will get the first candidate rejected? Can we explicitly, as a function of $M_1$, construct the $\mathbb{E}[\text{score of the first candidate}]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the calculation simpler, let's say the score is $U[0,1]$. First candidate is rejected if he score below $x$ and second candidate is rejected if he score below $y$, where $x,y\in[0,1]$.

- Probability that first candidate is accepted is $1-x$ with expected score $\frac{1+x}{2}$
- Probability that second candidate is accepted is $x(1-y)$ with expected score $\frac{1+y}{2}$
- Probability that third candidate is accepted is $xy$ with expected score $0.5$

The expected score of the three is then given below:

$$
\frac{1-x^{2}}{2}+x\frac{1-y^{2}}{2}+xy\frac{1}{2}
$$

We want to minimize this, so check point where partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ are zero:

$$
\begin{aligned}
-y^{2}+y+1-2x&=0 \\
x-2xy&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

We then get $x=\frac{5}{8}$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$. Scale back to 100 then we get $62.5$ and $50$ as the minimum score of acceptance for first and second candidate respectively.